# R downloaded stock prices differing

Tags: r

I am a day trader in INDIA. I have downloaded stock prices into r from YAHOO finance and from Quandl. But they are differing:

This is from YAHOO finance:

```
head(snl[[190]])
           SUZLON.NS.Open SUZLON.NS.High SUZLON.NS.Low SUZLON.NS.Close SUZLON.NS.Volume SUZLON.NS.Adjusted
2005-10-19         127.80         139.74        116.05          138.57        152125030           131.4587
2005-10-20         140.20         141.55        127.40          129.38         39078530           122.7403
2005-10-21         127.05         139.00        127.05          134.77         25623135           127.8537
2005-10-24         137.40         138.00        129.66          130.79         11125060           124.0779
2005-10-25         128.26         132.73        128.26          131.84          6320275           125.0740
2005-10-26         131.98         138.36        130.07          137.58         13556210           130.5195
```

This is from Quandl(from NSE(NATIONAL STOCK EXCHANGE of INDIA)):

```
mydata2 <- Quandl("NSE/SUZLON", type = "xts")
> head(mydata2)
             Open   High    Low   Last  Close Total Trade Quantity Turnover (Lacs)
2005-10-19 639.00 698.70 580.25 685.00 692.85             30425006       198742.85
2005-10-20 701.00 707.75 637.00 640.55 646.90              7815706        51594.41
2005-10-21 635.25 695.00 635.25 688.00 673.85              5124627        33589.12
2005-10-24 687.00 690.00 648.30 651.35 653.95              2225012        14857.01
2005-10-25 641.30 663.65 641.30 660.00 659.20              1264055         8298.54
2005-10-26 659.90 691.80 650.35 690.00 687.90              2711242        18417.62
```

Why are the stock prices differing? Should I trust the data from QUANDL/NSE as it is from the exchange itself?

Very many thanks for your time and effort...

Comment: you can check your data here if that helps : https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/archieve_eq.htm   .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your stock performed a 1 to 5 stock split in 2007. http://www.moneycontrol.com/company-facts/suzlonenergy/splits/SE17

Yahoo finance quotes on a split adjusted basis, hence the yahoo prices are exactly 1/5 of the quandl prices. The actual traded prices would be what you see in quandl, but any backtesting should be run on the yahoo prices, since you wouldn't actually incur any profit or loss from the split itself.